# C - Merging two sorted rows in a descending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am sorry if my code looks stupid but I am kind of new to the coding world.
The task is - I need to input all the elements of a rectangular matrix (no idea if it is the right word in programming) by columns, then I have to check if the row is in a descending order and here comes my problem. I need to merge two sorted by descending order rows and then to print it on the screen but I have no idea how to do that. I am trying 2-3 hours already. I will be very thankful if someone helps me. Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void enterArray(int masiv[][50],int n,int m);
void checkArray(int masiv[][50], int n, int m);
void merge(int masiv[][50], int n, int m);

int main()
{
    int a[50][50];
    int result, n, m;
    enterArray(a, n, m);
    checkArray(a, n, m);
    return 0;
}

void enterArray(int masiv[][50], int n, int m){
    int i,j;
    do{
        printf("Rows");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("Columns");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        if(m==n){
            printf("asd\n");
        }
    }while(n==m);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("Input the elements of the array by columns [%d][%d]\n",j,i);
            scanf("%d",&masiv[j][i]);
        }
}

void checkArray(int masiv[][50], int n, int m){
    int i,j;
    int flag=1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m-1;j++)
            if(masiv[i][j]<masiv[i][j+1])
                flag=0;
    if(flag==1)
        printf("\nRow %d is in a descending order",i);
}
```

Comment: 1) It is necessary to make it a pointer when inputting `m` and `n` in function. E.g `void enterArray(int masiv[][50], int *n, int *m);` call `enterArray(a, &n, &m);`

Comment: What does merging two rows have to do with detecting if the row is in descending order?

Comment: All *input* should be *validated*, at minimum, `if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) {... handle error ...}` for each place you take input. Otherwise, you may be processing garbage from the point of a failed conversion forward (not to mention if input is canceled with `ctrl+d` [or `ctrl+z` on windoze])

Comment: Moreover, what does "*I need to merge two sorted by descending order rows*" mean? Are you sure you are not supposed to simply sort the values in each *row* in decreasing order, then sort the array based on the initial value in each row. It is unclear what your goal is.